# Cannot inject any service annotated with @Transactional into any controller in 1.3.7

Tags: grails, transactions

i'm caught in a strange question about grails injection any service annotated with @Transactional into any controller in 1.3.7.

SyncSpInfoService：

```
 package test
 import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.*

 class SyncSpInfoService {
    static transactional = false
            @Transactional
    def syncSpInfoData(def dataSource)throws RuntimeException{
              ...
            }
```

Controller:

```
 package test
class SyncSpInfoController {
def syncSpInfoService
def dataSource
    def index = { 
    try{            
    syncSpInfoService.syncSpInfoData(dataSource)
    render  "Success"
    return
    }catch(RuntimeException e){
       e.printStackTrace()
       render "Error:"+e.getMessage()
       return
    }           
}
```

}

And run the controller,if the SyncSpInfoService is caugth in error,then i modify it,and run it again,there are errors as following:
Error:test.SyncSpInfoService cannot be cast to test.SyncSpInfoService

i don't why? Pls help me,thx a lot...

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the 'def' in your service method parameter:

```
    def syncSpInfoData(datasource) {} // and you don't need the throws
```

Comment: i add the detailed error:java.lang.ClassCastException: test.SyncSpInfoService cannot be cast to test.SyncSpInfoService      atjpayserver.SyncSpInfoService$$FastClassByCGLIB$$43e17ca2.invoke(<generated>)       atnet.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:149)    atorg.springframework.aop.framework.Cglib2AopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(Cglib2AopProxy.java:617)

Comment: Can you quickly do a 'grails clean' and then retry?  I could just be a weird class reload issue.

Comment: Once errors happened,i modify it and restart the grails project,and do a 'grails clean',do a 'grails run-app',it's ok with no error.And what makes me confused is that there is error in service executing,then will happen the error:test.SyncSpInfoService cannot be cast to test.SyncSpInfoService...